# How to append new row to dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

This is the code I have used:

```py
iname = "name1"    
ipassword = "password1"
iemail = "email@domain.com"
res1 = []
df = pd.read_csv("login.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
res1.append(iname,ipassword,iemail)
print(res1,res2,res3)
df.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

How to store the name, password and email in the csv file by using `pandas` dataframe?

`login.csv`:

```
name     password     email
admin    admin        asdfs
zds      sd           dsssfsfd
vipul    rao          dsfdsfs
```

Answer (score 67):

Another simple approach is to use [pd.Dataframe.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method.

```
row = [iname, ipassword, iemail]
df.loc[len(df)] = row
df.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Hi. That is a neat answer indeed. I was just curious to know why doesn't ```df.iloc[len(df)]=row``` work in this case?

Comment: @RaghavKumar Design decision, `iloc cannot enlarge its target object`, but `loc` can

Comment: @smcs What  does enlarging the target object mean?

Comment: @Connor The target object is the data frame, and after adding a new row, it is larger than before, depending on the number of columns.

Comment: @smcs Thanks so much! What is the efficiency of something like that? Is is quicker to use loc to enlarge the array or make something like a dictionary first?

Answer (score 9):

Use -

```
iname = "name1"    
ipassword = "password1"
iemail = "email@domain.com"

df2 = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[iname,ipassword,iemail]], columns
=df.columns))
df2.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

**Output**

```
    name   password             email
0  admin      admin             asdfs
1    zds         sd          dsssfsfd
2  vipul        rao           dsfdsfs
0  name1  password1  email@domain.com
```

Comment: this was just an example but its an user input so it has to a variable

Comment: @vipul-rao I have included the variables updated ans pls check. This will also support if you want to `append` multiple rows

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.loc` to add a row to your dataframe:

```
iname = "name1"    
ipassword = "password1"
iemail = "email@domain.com"

df = pd.read_csv("login.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")

df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = [iname, ipassword, iemail]

df.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to create an empty list first, populate it and then add to the empty data frame like this

```
data=[]

for i, row in new_df.head(4).iterrows():
    sequence=str(row['body'])
    author=row['author']
    data.append([author,sequence]) 
d=pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['author', 'results'])
```

it will give the results like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good if all you are doing is appending rows.  However, if you do other operations such as:

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'],inplace=True)`

then some of the index values will be greater than the size of the dataframe, and the accepted answer may overwrite an existing row.

In that case, I recommend:

```
row = [iname, ipassword, iemail]
df.loc[max(df.index)+1] = row
df.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

which, if the dataframe could be empty, may have to become:

```
row = [iname, ipassword, iemail]
if len(df.index)>0:
    df.loc[max(df.index)+1] = row
else:
    df.loc[len(df)] = row
df.to_csv("login.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: That should be the correct accepted answer. I have encountered same problem when I dropped a row and then tried to append a new one at the end with `df.loc[len(df)] = ...` and the last existing row got overwritten