# can not append new data to a pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, append

im trying to save some data in a dataframe, the first row of the dataframe should be ('Tom',.99, 'tom2'), supose i need to add ('mart',.3, 'mart2') row to the dataframe , i've tried to use append but is adding nothing this is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    trackeds = {'Name':['Tom'], 'proba':[.99],'name2':['tom2']}
    df_trackeds = pd.DataFrame(trackeds) 
    df_trackeds.append(pd.DataFrame({'name':['mart'],'proba': [.3],'name2':['mart2']}))
    print(df_trackeds)
```

the output is

```
Name  proba name2
0  Tom   0.99  tom2
```

i also tried to use

```
df_trackeds.append({'name':['mart'],'proba': [.3],'name2':['mart2']},ignore_index=True)
```

and

```
df_trackeds.append(pd.DataFrame({'name':['mart'],'proba': [.3],'name2':['mart2']}))
```

but nothing, i hope you can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Just for appending one row at a time.You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916371/how-to-append-new-row-to-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas function [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) not working inplace like pure python `append`, so is necessary assign back:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['mart'],'proba': [.3],'name2':['mart2']})
df_trackeds = df_trackeds.append(df, ignore_index=True)
print(df_trackeds)
   Name  proba  name2
0   Tom   0.99   tom2
1  mart   0.30  mart2
```

Comment: worked perfectly, in like twelve minutes i give you the best awnser =3